# Сравнение ключевых запросов с минус словами PHP

Tags: php

Мне нужно сделать такой инструмент, в 1 textarea должны быть фразы, а во 2 минус слова http://take.ms/rrPbsU. В 3 будут запросы которые пересекаются с минус словами, а в 4 запросы которые не пересекаются. Я закинул все в array и начал сравнять с функцией str_pos ничего не получилось, так же попробовал с помощью array_diff та же самая история, может быть я что то неправильно делаю, если есть у кого нибудь советы или решения то помогите буду очень рад помощи.

Comment: Приведите исходный код в своем вопросе.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$array = [
    'ключ 1',
    'ключ 2 с минусом',
    'ключ 3',
];

$minusArray = [
    'с минусом',
];

$withMinus = [];
$withoutMinus = [];

foreach ($array as $key => $value) {

    foreach ($minusArray as $minus) {
       if (strpos($minus, $value) === false) {
           $withoutMinus[] = $value;
           unset($array[$key]);
           break;
       }
       $withMinus[] = $value
    }

}

var_dump($withMinus);
var_dump($withoutMinus);
```

Как то так на скорую руку. Цикл в цикле, конечно не очень, но смотря сколько элементов планируется перебирать

Comment: только вместо `!strpos` правильно `strpos === false` т.к. `strpos` может вернуть `0`

Comment: Точно, спасибо за исправление. Обновил ответ

Comment: Огромное спасибо, я был близок к ответу но без вашей помочи не довел бы до конца)